# Allocating more memory to Rstudio

Tags: r

I am trying to run the function fviz_nbclust (factoextra package) to find the optimal # of clusters for a dataset of 5,900 variables and R returns with the error:

`Error: cannot allocate vector of size 133.3 Mb`

I've tried to increase the memory by changing memory.limit(). My current memory.limit is 4000 and my memory.size() is 997.38.

The exact function I'm using is:

`fviz_nbclust(top_usps_variables_scaled, FUNcluster = kmeans , method = "wss")`

Thanks!

Comment: What about run R without RStudio?

Comment: Does your computer have more than 4000 Mb of memory? If yes, are you running a 32-bit version of R? Check with `version()`